# read sended file from rest with php

Tags: php, node.js, rest, guzzle, sendfile

i have a node js api that send file like this

```
exports.myFunction = function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile("path_to_file");
}
```

and in php i try to read the file received like this :

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
 $res = $client->post('http://www.example.com',
 ['headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Bearer my token',
 'content-type' => 'application/json'
 ],
 'body' =>json_encode(['id'=>'5bf7c8cfe58e316de4d3ae89', 'type'=>'default'])
 ]);
 echo $res->getBody();
```

but i don't get the file, and i get this :

```
�PNG IHDR���f IDATx��w`U���of��g�zo �(�����O=���,�X���b�Į��N�қT!�PI
```

Comment: So you are sending a `.png` image file right?

Comment: Looks like you're echoing a binary string (probably your image). If you want to show the image, you need to add the correct headers before your echo: `header('Content-Type: image/png');`

Comment: i am sending the image, png or jpeg or other

Comment: how to set the header for the echo php ?